# Opening files after Tensorflow training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I made a training with tensorflow. As a result of the training I did, these files were formed. How can I open these files?

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mYMX.png][1]

ü

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Itdoesnt make a lot of sense

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.